# sorting a generic list of doubles

Tags: c#, .net, generic-list

I have a generic list of doubles that show on the page like this:

```
1199.17
1199.17
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1199.17
1349.17
1349.17
1349.17
1349.17
1349.17
1349.17
1311.67
1311.67
1311.67
1311.67
1311.67
1349.17
2174.17
2174.17
2174.17
2174.17
2136.67
2136.67
2136.67
2136.67
2174.17
2361.67
2361.67
2361.67
2361.67
2361.67
2361.67
2361.67
2361.67
2399.17
2849.17
2849.17
2849.17
2849.17
2849.17
2849.17
2849.17
2849.17
3111.67
3111.67
3111.67
3149.17
```

I am trying to order them so that the lowest double is first.

I tried doublePriceList.Sort() but this did not work.

How can I do this?

Comment: It should work, you need to show some of your code how and where you sort the list and where you display it.

Comment: When you say that something doesn't work, describe the *way* in which it doesn't work. Ideally, produce a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Note that it is advisable to use `decimal` for prices. This due to rounding differences.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;
```

and

```
var sortedList = doublePriceList.OrderBy(d => d);
```

Answer (score 10):

`Sort` (as per [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) works perfectly, although it isn't returning anything (isn't chainable):

```
var ds = new List<double>{
    2399.17,
    1199.17,
    // ...
};

ds.Sort();

foreach (double d in ds)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want to print them out

```
foreach( double d in doublePriceList.OrderBy( d => d ) )
{
  //print d
}
```