# c# using Linq to sort a list of decimals

Tags: c#, linq

As the title suggests, I have a list of prices that I wish to sort.
I tried doing this:

```
prices.Sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

but I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'.
>   Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

I tried to expand this an do something like

```
prices.Sort((a, b) {
    var x = double.Parse(a);
    var y = double.Parse(b);
    return x - y;
});
```

but I got the same error.
Does anyone know how I can do this easily?

Comment: What is the type of prices List<T> T is ? Can you give an example of the list and how you want to be sorted ?

Comment: Have a look at the signature of the overload of `List<T>.Sort` you're trying to call. How do you expect it to work? I'd suggest either using LINQ and `OrderBy` instead, or using `decimal.Compare` as a comparison... or just call `Sort` without any arguments.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233179/sorting-a-generic-list-of-doubles

Comment: I'm adding the answer here, since the topic seems to be closed. You are using a `IComparer` in `Sort`. `IComparer` expects to return eiterh 1,0 or -1 depending on the given compareable values. Therefore you've two decimals to compare, and you've to return an int as the result.

See  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare(v=vs.110).aspx for further details

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) and [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
prices=prices.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```